# Skip item in foreach knockout js array?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, foreach

i have this question about a foreach in knockout js and the first item.
I want to skip the first one and iterate over the next items.

The main issue is that i wanna do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="text: ItemsArray[0].someProperty"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach: ItemsArray"> <!-- here i must skip the first item -->
     <div data-bind="text: someProperty"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think knockoutJS provides a function to skip a specific element in an Array, but you can use a small trick.

If you want to skip only the first item, you can use the `$index` property:

```
<div data-bind="text: ItemsArray[0].someProperty"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach: ItemsArray">
<!-- ko if: $index() != 0 -->
     <div data-bind="text: someProperty"></div>
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: That index, should be != 0?

Comment: That worked for me! thanks! i just have to modify a little your code first with the $index() because it is an observable and then changing the != 1 to != 0.