# Knockoutjs template foreach, special first item

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-validate

So i have been busting my brain figuring this out. I have a foreach, spitting out templates, and i want the first element to have a special attribute. So far solutions i have found havent worked.

This is the foreach:

```
<h3 class="question">Geografi</h3>   
        <p class="answer" data-bind="template: { name: 'geographyTmpl', foreach: geographyList,  templateOptions: { selections: selectedGeographies } }"></p>
```

This is the template:

```
<script id="geographyTmpl" type="text/html">
<input class="geoCheckList" validate="required:true, minlength:2" name="geoCheckList[]" type="checkbox" data-bind='value: $data, attr: { id: "Geo"+$index()},checked: $root.selectedGeographies' />
<label data-bind="text: $data, attr: { 'for': 'Geo'+$index()}"></label>
```

And i want to add: "validate="required:true, minlength:2" to the first element.

What do i need to do?

If it helps, its for jQuery validation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

check my answer for another question about the first element in KnockoutJS `foreach`

[Skip item in foreach knockout js array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300322/skip-item-in-foreach-knockout-js-array/15300548#15300548)

```
<div data-bind="text: ItemsArray[0].someProperty"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach: ItemsArray">
<!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
     <div data-bind="text: someProperty"></div>
 <!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: $index() != 0 -->
    <div data-bind="text: anotherDifferentProperty"></div>    
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I still have some trouble with validation, but at least i can now have a special first item.

Comment: What's incredibly frustrating is that attempting to use that same thing in an actual "if" in data-bind doesn't work (I'm switching on the iterated variable, so my use case is a bit different...)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a computed observable to return a boolean and if the boolean is true you show the attribute(standard knockout)?

something like this maybe

```
this.IsFirst = ko.computed(function() {
    return this == Array[0];
}, this);
```

it seems hacky but should work

or use

```
   {{if $item.first === $data}}
```

Comment: Also thank you for your contribution :) i have already found a suitable answer, but i will save this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) rather than a template, and then get the $index off the bindingContext, and add the validate attribute only when $index is 0.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Create your input and label elements here then
        $(element).append(// add your new elements in here);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution :) i have already found a suitable answer, but i will save this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

A post from earlier works as long as you taking off the parentheses off the index.

Like the following

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: ItemsArray">
<!-- ko if: $index == 0 -->
     <div data-bind="text: someProperty"></div>
 <!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: $index != 0 -->
    <div data-bind="text: anotherDifferentProperty"></div>    
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```