# dynamic bootstrap tabs with list of knockout observablearry

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm getting a list from my backend, that's filled with entities(each entity has several properties) I need to display or edit. I want to do this using bootstrap tabs. One entity per tab. The amount of entities in my list varies, so I want to do this within a ko foreach loop. It's quite similar to this one: [Knockoutjs template foreach, special first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340145/knockoutjs-template-foreach-special-first-item)
with the difference that I can't get mine to work.
I can click the tabs in the navbar and they show the switching correctly. The tab-content stays empty, tough.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <!-- ko foreach: vm.entities -->
    <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: { href: Id , title: Name},text: Name"></a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $index() != 0 -->
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: { href: Id , title: Name},text: Name"></a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <!-- ko foreach: vm.entities -->
        <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
            <div data-bind="attr: {'id': Id}" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $index() != 0 -->
            <div data-bind="attr: {'id': Id}" class="tab-pane fade">
        <!-- /ko -->

        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>and some other stuff I need to display...

        <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $index() != 0 -->
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: u should up your model applybinding script, too.

Comment: I'm using a custom framework which takes care of my modelbinding. However, I don't think it's important. My entites is a ko.observableArray() and I map the data from my backend with $(document).ready(function () { ko.mapping.fromJSON(ko.toJSON(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.listOfEntites))), {}, vm.entities);
});
Did the same on several other pages and never had an issue with that.

Comment: because i want to test and find out what happen, it more easier for me if i have binding script. now i read ur html and create my model depend ur html.it hard for people need test it for u.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell much from your question. But the problem might be this

```
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: { href: Id , title: Name},text: Name"></a></li>
```

I assume the ID here will be just a normal ID which won't start with `#`. For this tab to point to the right content, it requires the href specify the id of the right content. To do this it requires the prefix `#`. So it should be like this instead.

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: { href: '#' + Id , title: Name}, text: Name"></a></li>
```

Comment: you were right about the problem, it was missing the '#'. but your way of solving it did not work for me. however, I solved it by adding a new property that adds the '#' and the id in the backend already.
So thanks for the help, without you I would probably have searched way longer...

Comment: @lupus great that I can help :) I just removed the purposed solution then. Btw for the closing div </div>, you don't need to check if the index is not 0 or equals to 0. Because either way the closing statement will look the same </div>